# What is the meaning of the expression " pull it yourself"?

Tags: meaning

I have come across this sentence in a book, but I didn't and don’t quite understand its meaning. I have two suggestions.  In the first case, it literally means dragging, and in the other, dealing with the situation or the problem.
I have checked a lot of information, but didn't find anything useful.
The sentence from the book: “There’s folks out lately that would kill you for a pair of pennies, let alone a horse and cart. What are you going to do now? **Pull it yourself**?”

Comment: You need to provide more context. This isn't an idiom, it seems like it's just referring to the horse and cart - ie are you going to pull the cart yourself?

Answer (score 4):

This is not a question of grammar or usage.

That sentence is taken from [*The Name of the Wind*](https://www.penguin.com/ajax/books/excerpt/9780756405892). It comes a few lines after this:

> “I’m fine. I got cut up a little, but the blood is mostly Nelly’s. It jumped on her. Killed her about two miles outside town, past the Oldstone Bridge.”

The book opens with the action already under way. You are supposed to infer that **Nelly** is the character's horse, and that **it** refers to the cart the horse was pulling. Hence the question,

> "What are you going to do now? Pull **it** [the cart] yourself?"